# How to update / refresh div tag in ajax in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have checkboxes (initially none selected) in a loop and want to show additional icon next to the checkbox but ONLY when the checkbox is selected. I have included "if" statement but when the user selects a checkbox the icon does not appear. How can I do this

```
<div id="divItems">
<table> <thead></thead><tbody>
@foreach (Employee item in Model)
{
   <tr>
        <td> <label class="checkbox">
             <input type="checkbox" name="@(item.Name)" id="@(item.Name)"              class="clink" value="(item.FullName)" /> @item.Name  </label>
        </td>
        <td>
             <a href="#MModal" class="open-Modal" data-id="(item.MapSPNames)" 
                  data-toggle="modal">  
               <i class="icon-edit" title="Filter"></i>  
             </a>
         </td>  

   </tr>
}
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you calling the .ajax on change of checkbox?

Comment: Naveen I am fetching other data from the controller which updates other parts of the page - I thought when it does an ajax call I can update my div tag at same time

Comment: Assuming `clink` is spelled correctly in code.  Should be `click`

Comment: So the .ajax result will not affect the <div id="divItems">? It means you want to display the <i class="icon-edit" title="Filter"></i> only after those checkbox which are checked. correct?

Comment: Use developer tools to determine if the icon-edit is getting written to the HTML.  If not, I'd put an `alert(Request[item.Name])` inside the `if` statement to verify the value is correct.

Comment: #L_7337 click is simply a class name & the ajax request is definitely fired. #Naveen yes correct the filter icon should only be displayed next to each checkbox only when it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Make a function and call it wherever you want:

```
  function showChecked() {
     $(".open-Modal").each(function () {
         $(this).hide();
     });
  $(".clink").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
       $(this).parent().next().find(".open-Modal").show();
   else
      $(this).parent().next().find(".open-Modal").hide();
  });
  }
```

Now call the function showChecked(), according to your need. Like on change of the checkbox:

```
$(".clink").on("change", function () {
  showChecked();
});
```

Also call this function on $(document).ready or where you are loading the html of your div id="divItems"

Comment: Naveen thanks but I would like to keep the html outside the jquery - is there something where we can show/hide it from jquery ?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please ask anything in case you have any query.

Comment: Naveen I tried your above solution but it does NOT work. I have updated my code above to show my exact code c# razor - pls see if I am doing anything wrong. thanks

Comment: Naveen it still is not working - it definitely is executing the each function and is checking if checked but the line "$(this).parent().next().find(".icon-edit").show();" is not doing anything. I am running showChecked() inside the .clink.on change function as you mentioned.

Comment: you icon is displayed by <i class="icon-edit" title="Filter"></i> ?

Comment: Yes which is inside the <a href> tag as in my code above .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54196/discussion-between-user2906420-and-naveen-chandra-tiwari).

Comment: Why are you putting this inside the <a href>? is there any specific reason? Try to place this outside the <a href> then try the code.

Comment: Yes because the icon is simply a link which opens up my modal so i need it tobe inside the <a href> - can we use the <a href> class rather then the icon-edit class to be accurate